# how to get values from previous activity

Tags: android

hi all
in second activity i set some values and how to bring into first activity. i use Bundle for bring data. NullPointerException error is getting.

in secondactivity:

```
    c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            c1.setChecked(true); 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key1",String.valueOf(c1.getText()));
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), main.class);
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
```

in first(main) activity:

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    check = bundle.getString("key1"); // NullPointerException.
```

please assist me.

Comment: Are you sure that String.valueOf(c1.getText()) is returning some value and not null.

Comment: it is not null in the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are launching your `secondactivity` from your `firstactivity` (main). In this case, you need to return the data using `finish()` and not again start the first activity using `startActivityForResult()`.

In your `secondactivity`, use:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1",String.valueOf(c1.getText()));
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), main.class);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);
finish();
```

And in the `onActivityResult()` of `firstactivity`, use:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data)
{
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    check = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("key1") : "";
}
```

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult  on this line  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data). i put it in OnCreate method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [Start Activity For Result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) mechanism. So when the second activity is done to return the result to the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

Mojo Risin is right you have to use Start Activity For Result mechanism.

You can see complete working tutorial here http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),detailPage.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("prodId", "data");
            startActivity(myIntent);
```

to fetch

```
String index=""
index=getIntent().getExtras().getString("prodId");
System.out.println("Position :"+index);
```