# Get data from current activity to previous in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

This is My Current Activity code

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("BonusScore", score);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
```

Now i want `BonusScore` in previous activity.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // TODO Extract the data returned from the child Activity.
              BonusScore = Bonus.getIntExtra("BonusScore", 0);
              Log.d("splash_bonus", BonusScore+"");
          }
}
```

I tried this code but not working
please help me ,thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling the second Activity with `startActivity(intent)` or `startActivityForResult(intent)`?

Comment: what is the `Bonus`? you need get data from `Intent data`, so your code must be like: `data.getIntExtra("BonusScore", 0);`

Comment: Bonus is key associated with int variable score

Comment: @indivisible please post ur answer for better idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get values from previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814366/how-to-get-values-from-previous-activity)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot, it's not really worthy of being an answer - it was a request for clarification/more information. I wanted to know how you were calling the second Activity from the first. And it also looks like the existing answers are more likely the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to do.

```
int bonus = data.getIntExtra("BonusScore", 0);
```

you must have to do this code in your `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line :

```
 BonusScore = Bonus.getIntExtra("BonusScore", 0);
```

with :

```
BonusScore = data.getIntExtra("BonusScore", 0);
```

That should do it.